# How do I keep the connection open to mariadb in nodejs using mariasql?

Tags: node.js, mariadb, mariasql

I use NodeJS, MariaDB and [mariasql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mariasql) to store some data when a socket event occurres. The event can occur every 10 minutes or delay up to hours.

Now I wonder if a connection timeout will occure, when there are no query executions for a long time.

My second question is: Do I have to execute .end() after every query and reestablish the connection if I need to execute another query later.

Thats the simple code

```
db.query(
    'INSERT INTO log (log_id, data) VALUES (?, ?)',
    [ 1, 'log..' ],
    function(error, result) {
        ...
    }
);

db.end(); // Do I have to end the connection and reestablish later?
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really bad form to try to keep a connection open for 'hours'.  There could be a network glitch or other glitch.  You are chewing up resources on the MySQL server.  Etc.

In any case, you should be ready to handle lost of connection, so you may as well close the connection so that *usually* things happen predictably.

Comment: It appears that mariasql handels this automatically fortunately. But node-mysql had to specially configured for this.